# Create a drupal 6 views slideshow from a single content type that has both, image and video fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, slideshow, drupal-views

I need a little direction.  I've created a content type that has both, images and videos attached to a node.  I need to create a single frame slideshow that riffles through the mixed media.  Currently, I'm using the Embedded Media Field as well as the ImageField to upload the content.  I'd like to keep that within the same content type if possible.  I was considering separating them and then using taxonomy to make them relational, but that sounds convoluted.  At this point, the slideshow displays them both, together.

[image: screenshot of my view]

Could I add both fields to an array in a template file, then return them as one field?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add some markup that encapsulates both fields. If that is the case, you can re-write the output of the fields.

Try this:

1. Edit the "Content: Slideshow main image" field
2. Enable "Exclude from display"
3. Click Update
4. Edit the "Content: Upload Full Size Video" field
5. Enable "Rewrite the output of this field"
6. Here you can add whichever markup you want and make use of the field tokens. For example, something like `<div>[field_slideshow]<br>[field_upload]</div>` Note: The token values will depend on the names of your CCK fields.

Also, for Drupal related questions, there is a separate [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) exchange where you might get more targeted help.

Comment: Thanks, but rewriting the output gives me the same result, which is both fields joined together, where as I need them to be treated as one slide per media type.

Comment: @knice - Is it ever the case that one slide has both an image and a video?

Comment: Well, technically yes if the user adds their own custom thumbnail.  Besides that, there should only be one type of media displayed at a time.

Comment: @knice - Have you tried enabling the "Hide if empty" option for both fields?

Comment: Still the same result.